# Using Jensen's inequality prove: (1) $~n!<n^n<(n!)^2$ for $n>1$ and (2) $~e^n\geqslant \frac{n^n}{n!}.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

> Using Jensen's inequality, prove: 
>   $$~(1) ~~n!<n^n<(n!)^2~~~~~ and ~~~(2)~~~ e^n\geqslant \frac{n^n}{n!}.$$

**Attempt.** For (1), since $\log$ is strictly concave, using Jensen:
$$\log\frac{1+2+\ldots+n}{n}>\frac{\log1+\log2+\ldots+\log n}{n}$$
equivalently
$$\log\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}{n}>\frac{\log n!}{n}$$
equivalently
$$\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)^n> n!,$$
and since $\frac{n+1}{2}<n$ (for $n>1$), we get the first part. How can one get the second part?

Is $(2)$ a consequence of $(1)$ (regarding somehow that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<e$)?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Yep I've mispelled it

Comment: As an aside, if $n\in \mathbb{N}$, then (2) follows immediately from the Taylor series expansion of $e^n$ ($e^n =\sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{n^k}{k!}$).

Comment: Also, note that $(2!)^2 = 2^2$, so the first inequality holds only for $n > 2$.